# Trying to Connect Azure DataLake using Managed access but getting unauthorized error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-lake, azure-managed-identity

```
string dfsUri = "https://" + accountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net";
DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(dfsUri), new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()));
DataLakeFileSystemClient dataLakeFileSystemClient = await dataLakeServiceClient.CreateFileSystemAsync("test1");
DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient = await dataLakeFileSystemClient.CreateDirectoryAsync("my-directory");
DataLakeFileClient fileClient = await directoryClient.CreateFileAsync("uploaded-file.txt");
FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("");
long fileSize = fileStream.Length;
await fileClient.AppendAsync(fileStream, offset: 0);
await fileClient.FlushAsync(position: fileSize);
```

Trying to Connect Azure DataLake using Managed Identity but getting unauthorized error on line:

```
DataLakeFileSystemClient dataLakeFileSystemClient = await dataLakeServiceClient.CreateFileSystemAsync("test1");
```

> error message : This request is not authorized to perform this operation , Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)\r\nErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure

Comment: What IAM roles does the MSI have in the ADLS account?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your managed identity has atleast storage data blob reader or storage data blob contributor roles.

To know assign managed identity access to resource using Azure portal check below link: [Assign a managed identity access to a resource by using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/howto-assign-access-portal)

To know details of roles available in ask gen2 check below link: [Access control model in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control-model#role-based-access-control-azur)

Could you please let us know, what roles you have granted for managed identity?